# Get the value of selection option and then use it to search/filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search page, after i search the result is displayed on this page.

After i get on search page there is a search box and a category filter.

When i select a option in filter it should auto search via JavaScript without refreshing page. I want this user friendly and light as far as possible.

```css
form {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: #243b5e;
    min-width: 900px;
}

form input {
    background-color: #f6f6f6 !important;
    padding: 15px 55px 15px 40px !important;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    color: #243b5e;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.top-search .searching-word {
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
 border: 0;
 width: 75%;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
}

form .search-button-wrapper {
    top: 4px;
    left: -50px;
    position: relative;
}

 form .search-select {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #243b5e;
    }
```

```html
<div class="cw-wrapper">
  <form action="http://realbusinessanalytics.com" method="get" class="top-search">

    <input class="searching-word" name="s" placeholder="Search LBS by … " value="global" type="text">
    <a href="#" class="search-button-wrapper">
      <button class="search-button">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#3B465C" stroke-width="1.3" transform="translate(1 1)">
                                    <circle cx="5.5" cy="5.5" r="5.5"></circle>
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" d="M9.5 9.5l4.528 4.528"></path>
                                </g>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
    </a>


    <select name="c" id="searchselect" class="search-select">
      <option class="search-placeholder" value="" disabled="" selected="">ALL RESULTS</option>
      <option value="59">Accounting, Finance and Economics</option>
      <option value="26">Advisory Board</option>
      <option value="34">Alumni Team</option>
      <option value="43">Business and economic outlook</option>
      <option value="78">Business Ethics</option>
      <option value="39">Case analysis</option>
      <option value="65">Executive Programmes</option>
      <option value="73">Faculty directory profiles</option>
      <option value="82">Finance</option>
      <option value="56">General Management Programme</option>
      <option value="18">In the Media</option>
      <option value="38">LBS Insight</option>
      <option value="61">Marketing and Sales Management</option>
      <option value="19">News</option>
      <option value="57">Open Seminars</option>
      <option value="60">Operations and Management Information System</option>
      <option value="63">Personal Leadership and Human Resources Management</option>
      <option value="17">Press Releases</option>
      <option value="89">Research news</option>
      <option value="64">Sector Specific</option>
      <option value="62">Strategy, Innovation and Governance</option>
      <option value="1">Uncategorized</option>
    </select>
    <!--            <div class="search-x">&#215;</div>-->
  </form>
  <hr>
  <div class="cw-70">


    <h1>SEARCH RESULTS</h1>
    <!--        <h1>Search by: "-->
    <!--"</h1>-->
    <!--        -->
    <!--                <div class="searching-item">-->
    <!--                    <a href="-->
    <!--"> <h3>-->
    <!--</h3></a>-->
    <!--                    -->
    <!--                </div>-->
    <!--                -->
    <!--            <div class="searching-item"> <h3>Nothing found</h3></div>-->
    <!--            -->
    <div class="searching-item">
      <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/%e2%80%8bogechi-adeola/">
        <h3>​Ogechi Adeola</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="searching-item">
      <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/%e2%80%8bdavid-west-olayinka/">
        <h3>Olayinka David-West</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="searching-item">
      <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/udoji-uchora/">
        <h3>Uchora Udoji</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="searching-item">
      <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/akin-o%e2%80%8b%e2%80%8bparison/">
        <h3>Akin O​​parison</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="searching-item">
      <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/emenalo-chukwunonye%e2%80%8b/">
        <h3>Chukwunonye Emenalo</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="searching-item">
      <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/omoregie-kayode/">
        <h3>Kayode Omoregie</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="searching-item">
      <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/okonedo-enase/">
        <h3>Enase Okonedo</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="searching-item">
      <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/onwuegbuzie-henrietta/">
        <h3>Henrietta Onwuegbuzie</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="searching-item">
      <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/ogunyemi-kemi/">
        <h3>Kemi Ogunyemi</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="searching-item">
      <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/owolabi-akintola/">
        <h3>Akintola Owolabi</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem i am facing currently is that each time i am selecting a filter option i need to click on search button to show results and it refreshes page as well. I need it to be automatic without page reload.

Below is the js i am thinking to use but it didn't work. Any Help to make it work will be appreciated.

**The current url format is example.com?s=SEARCH-STRING&c=value**

**Value should come from dropdown option for reference**

```
$('#searchselect').change(function (e) {
            var searchText = $('#searchQuery').val();
            var section = $(this).val();

            if (section != '') {
                var hash = '?s=' + global + '&c=' + section  ;
                window.location.hash = hash;
            } else {
                var hash = '?s=' + global + '&c=' + section ;
                window.location.hash = hash;
            }
        });
```

Comment: did you find the solution you are looking for?

Comment: @chebaby No i didn't can you please help me?

Comment: I would be glad to help you @Nimesh

Comment: @chebaby Please check my comment below with screenshot on your answer

Comment: @chebaby can you please edit your code according to the comment i attached in you answer

Comment: @chebaby can you please check my comment below your answer again. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Client side

```js
$('#searchselect').on('change', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();

 var searchText   = $('input[name=s]').val();
 var section      = $(this).val();
 
 var query_params = '?s=' + searchText + '&c=' + section;

 // send ajax request to avoid page reload

 $.ajax({

  url: 'http://realbusinessanalytics.com' + query_params,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'html',
        beforeSend: function() {

            $('.search-results-wrapper').html('<h2>Please wait...</h2><hr>');
        }
 })
 .done(function(results) {

        $('.search-results-wrapper').html(results);

  // update the url
        window.history.pushState({},"", query_params);
 });
 
});
```

```css
form {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: #243b5e;
    min-width: 900px;
}

form input {
    background-color: #f6f6f6 !important;
    padding: 15px 55px 15px 40px !important;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    color: #243b5e;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.top-search .searching-word {
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
 border: 0;
 width: 75%;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
}

form .search-button-wrapper {
    top: 4px;
    left: -50px;
    position: relative;
}

form .search-select {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #243b5e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="cw-wrapper">

<form action="http://realbusinessanalytics.com" method="get" class="top-search">

 <input class="searching-word" name="s" placeholder="Search LBS by … " value="global" type="text">

 <a href="#" class="search-button-wrapper">
  <button class="search-button">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
   <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#3B465C" stroke-width="1.3" transform="translate(1 1)">
    <circle cx="5.5" cy="5.5" r="5.5"></circle>
    <path stroke-linecap="round" d="M9.5 9.5l4.528 4.528"></path>
   </g>
   </svg>
  </button>
 </a>


 <select name="c" id="searchselect" class="search-select">
  <option class="search-placeholder" value="" disabled="" selected="">ALL RESULTS</option>
  <option value="59">Accounting, Finance and Economics</option>
  <option value="26">Advisory Board</option>
  <option value="34">Alumni Team</option>
  <option value="43">Business and economic outlook</option>
  <option value="78">Business Ethics</option>
  <option value="39">Case analysis</option>
  <option value="65">Executive Programmes</option>
  <option value="73">Faculty directory profiles</option>
  <option value="82">Finance</option>
  <option value="56">General Management Programme</option>
  <option value="18">In the Media</option>
  <option value="38">LBS Insight</option>
  <option value="61">Marketing and Sales Management</option>
  <option value="19">News</option>
  <option value="57">Open Seminars</option>
  <option value="60">Operations and Management Information System</option>
  <option value="63">Personal Leadership and Human Resources Management</option>
  <option value="17">Press Releases</option>
  <option value="89">Research news</option>
  <option value="64">Sector Specific</option>
  <option value="62">Strategy, Innovation and Governance</option>
  <option value="1">Uncategorized</option>
 </select>

</form>

<hr>

<div class="cw-70">
 <h1>SEARCH RESULTS</h1>
 <div class="searching-item">
  <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/%e2%80%8bogechi-adeola/">
  <h3>​Ogechi Adeola</h3>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="searching-item">
  <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/%e2%80%8bdavid-west-olayinka/">
  <h3>Olayinka David-West</h3>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="searching-item">
  <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/udoji-uchora/">
  <h3>Uchora Udoji</h3>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="searching-item">
  <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/akin-o%e2%80%8b%e2%80%8bparison/">
  <h3>Akin O​​parison</h3>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="searching-item">
  <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/emenalo-chukwunonye%e2%80%8b/">
  <h3>Chukwunonye Emenalo</h3>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="searching-item">
  <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/omoregie-kayode/">
  <h3>Kayode Omoregie</h3>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="searching-item">
  <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/okonedo-enase/">
  <h3>Enase Okonedo</h3>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="searching-item">
  <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/onwuegbuzie-henrietta/">
  <h3>Henrietta Onwuegbuzie</h3>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="searching-item">
  <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/ogunyemi-kemi/">
  <h3>Kemi Ogunyemi</h3>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="searching-item">
  <a href="http://realbusinessanalytics.com/f_r_colade_team/owolabi-akintola/">
  <h3>Akintola Owolabi</h3>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

## Server side

```
<?php 

// Check if the request is an Ajax request

if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' ): ?>

    <h2>
        <?php global $wp_query; echo 'Search Result for&nbsp;'; echo get_search_query(). '&nbsp; &mdash; &nbsp; ('; echo $wp_query->found_posts.') &nbsp; results found.'; ?>
    </h2>
    <hr>

    <?php 

    if (have_posts()) : 

        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="searching-item">

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>

            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

            </div>

        <?php endwhile;

    else: ?>

        <div class="searching-item"><h3>Nothing found</h3></div>



<?php else: ?>

    // If the request is not an Ajax request (GET request) 
    // show the page
    // ...
```

Comment: It doesn't filters without clicking, please check

Comment: I found something this will able to help you to fix it, when i click on dropdown, it add extra parameter which we don't need, Please check this link https://prnt.sc/ki4jn6

Comment: I tried with the js you gave please check the result here  http://realbusinessanalytics.com/?s=global     by clicking on dropdown, nothing happens, search results remains the same

Comment: I checked please check the url http://realbusinessanalytics.com/?s=global again on how it is working, it refreshes the page, i need to do without page refresh. Please help me

Comment: Actually it's not the "traditional" reloading, anyway i know what you want to achieve, i will help you. what you want is to only refresh the search result section without reloading the whole page. but here's the thing, your query results returned by ajax request is sending the whole html page, that why you think the page is reloading.
what i want you to do is to create an entry point that sends only the search results, not the entire page.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i saw your profile you are WordPress developer as well, the website is in WordPress. Do you think it will help you to solve?

Comment: in matter of fact, i don't think of myself as a Wordpress developer, i frequently use laravel for backend... you just remind me to update my bio :-) anyway, i would be glad to help you @Nimesh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178125/discussion-between-nimesh-and-chebaby).

Comment: Can you please post the right answer to the answer. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using ajax call to fill data in search results like below in 'searchselect' change event with proper conditions:

$.ajax
({
 
 type: "POST",
 
 url: "http://realbusinessanalytics.com" + "?s=" + global + "&c=" + section,
 
 success: function(data){

 `"Write you custom code here"`

}});

Append "data" to whatever element you want to fill

This will not load the page and get the data as well.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/605309/
Please make changes as per your requirements; this is only for demo purpose.
For the question above append your ajax data in "cw-70" class.

Comment: sorry but what is not working, ajax call or logic to append data or my link?

Comment: please check the below answer he is close but a bit of error

Comment: try to empty query_params value in ajax.done function. I think you would mistakenly have declared that variable as a global variable. 
And for button click if you want you could call the function on search box text change event rather than dropdown change event.

Comment: Can you please fix the issue and write a working code of it, i am new to ajax