# How to add flex in inline css instead of block via jQuery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have simple javascript used to show and hide items on button click and vice versa.

1. Currently what it does when i click on **Load More** button it adds `stlye="display: block;"`  to the `div.item selector`
2. And when i click on **Show Less** Button it adds `stlye="display: none;"` to the `div.item selector`

I need to add `stlye="display: flex;"` instead of `stlye="display: block;"`

When clicked on **Load More** Button

Here is the js, but i have no idea what to change

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Load the first 3 list items from another HTML file
//$('#myList2').load('externalList.html div.item:lt(3)');
$('#myList2 div.item:lt(3)').show();
$('#showLess').hide();
var items =  8;
var shown =  3;
$('#loadMore').click(function () {
    $('#showLess').show();
    shown = $('#myList2 div.item:visible').size()+2;
    if(shown< items) {$('#myList2 div.item:lt('+shown+')').show();}
    else {$('#myList2 div.item:lt('+items+')').show();
         $('#loadMore').hide();
         }
});
$('#showLess').click(function () {
    $('#myList2 div.item').not(':lt(3)').hide();
    $('#loadMore').show();
    $('#showLess').hide();
});
});
```

Please help, i think it's a simple fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing .show() to .css() and passing in ('display','flex') will give you the desired effect.

However, i'd personally never recommend doing css in the js files, i'll almost always toggle a class to handle this, that way the next developer that comes along knows where to look to change the css ;)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Load the first 3 list items from another HTML file
  //$('#myList2').load('externalList.html div.item:lt(3)');
  $('#myList2 div.item:lt(3)').show();
  $('#showLess').hide();
  var items = 8;
  var shown = 3;
  $('#loadMore').click(function () {
    $('#showLess').show();
    shown = $('#myList2 div.item:visible').size() + 2;
    if (shown < items) {
      $('#myList2 div.item:lt(' + shown + ')').css('display', 'flex');
    } else {
      $('#myList2 div.item:lt(' + items + ')').css('display', 'flex');
      $('#loadMore').hide();
    }
  });
  $('#showLess').click(function () {
    $('#myList2 div.item').not(':lt(3)').hide();
    $('#loadMore').show();
    $('#showLess').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your Code Works Great, Only problem i am facing now is by default when nothing is clicked it is adding block by default, i need to change that  flex as well. can you please edit your answer according to that

Comment: I've given you the guidance you need to do it ;) .show() will add 'display:block' to 'show' something. If you want a different display property, then you'll need to change any .show() to the .css() code above.

Comment: Thanks Man, you have Clear Concept on js :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Keep display: flex by default in CSS and

Change .hide() to  .css("display", "none");

Change .show() to  .css("display", "");

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    // Load the first 3 list items from another HTML file
    //$('#myList2').load('externalList.html div.item:lt(3)');
    $('#myList2 div.item:lt(3)').css("display", "");
    $('#showLess').css("display", "none");
    var items = 8;
    var shown = 3;
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        $('#showLess').css("display", "");
        shown = $('#myList2 div.item:visible').size() + 2;
        if (shown < items) { $('#myList2 div.item:lt(' + shown + ')').css("display", ""); }
        else {
            $('#myList2 div.item:lt(' + items + ')').css("display", "");
            $('#loadMore').css("display", "none");
        }
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        $('#myList2 div.item').not(':lt(3)').css("display", "none");
        $('#loadMore').css("display", "");
        $('#showLess').css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

Comment: Will this add flex to the inline css? while i click on load more?

Comment: Keep display: flex by default in CSS . Why do you want to add flex as inline style ?

Comment: I need this for center alignment, Please provide me a way to do it via js

Comment: Just change .css("display", ""); to css("display", "flex"); in the above solution

Comment: I have a problem when i click it works as you said, but when i don't click by default it is adding block, can we change that as well?

Comment: As I told you earlier, add css by default for that #myList2 div.item { display: flex}

Comment: Via js do like this     $('#myList2 div.item:lt(3)').css("display", "flex");

Comment: Can you Please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821801/get-the-value-of-selection-option-and-then-use-it-to-search-filter

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.css()` function instead of `.show()` and `.hide()`.

So when you use:

```
$('#loadMore').show();
$('#loadMore').hide();
```

It can be replaced with:

```
$('#loadMore').css('display', 'flex');
$('#loadMore').css('display', 'none');
```

Replace that for any element you want to be `display: flex` instead of `display: block`.

Also make sure for those elements to start them with the correct styles in your css.

Comment: Can you please post an edited version of your code in mine? :)

Comment: There is enough here for you to continue, we're here to help, not do it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot i got your idea :)

Answer (score 0):

`$('#flexelement').show();` always puts display:block on the element.

if you need it to be flex you have to change the css directly without the shortcut. try using

```
$('#flexelement').css('display', 'flex');
```

instead of

```
$('#flexelement').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ι would propose to use jQuery addClass and removeClass functions and handle the css rules in a css file instead of inlining the css rules.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showLess').hide();
    var items =  8;
    var shown =  3;
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        $('#showLess').show();
        shown = shown + 2;
        if (shown < items) {
            var showItems = show;
        }
        else {
            var showItems = items;
            $('#loadMore').hide();
        }
        $('#myList2 div.item:lt(' + showItems + ')').addClass('shown-items');
    });

    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        shown = 3;
        $('#myList2 div.item').not(':lt(3)').removeClass('shown-items');
        $('#loadMore').show();
        $('#showLess').hide();
    });
});
```

And in your css file:

```
div.item{
    display: none;
}

div.item.shown-items{
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind adding it to my code so that i can try if it works?